# How to add website password athentication for my Linux server webhost application

Tags: linux, security, authentication, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I am a Linux server beginner. In fact I am a beginner at a lot of the stuff I am trying to figure out. Therefore, I suspect much of my troubles are due to the fact I don’t know the right words to figure out what I am trying to do.

I am hosting an Ubuntu Linux server using a mirco AWS EC2 instance. On my server I have a number of server applications running, but one in particular is causing me problems.

I am using an independent free server application that hosts (not on port 80) a webpage for everyone to access. The same application has a pay version which adds a tons of features as well as the feature I need – namely, the ability to password protect the website. The free version I have does not even allow the ability to utilize proxy settings.

I would like to know what I need in order to force the webpage traffic through some authentication system before users have access to the sensitive data.

I have thought of a few possible methods so far:
1)  reverse proxy server? (Although I cannot set up the app to use a proxy)
2)  Use EC2 firewall IP address restriction to only accept traffic from another server (or my computer), and then require that server to authenticate access. 
3)  Some sort of access gateway or extra firewall installed on (and on top of) the EC2 instances that requires authentication over top of the running application.
4)  Paying for some sort of (reverse) VPN service that forces web traffic through password authentication before allowing access to my website.  
5)  Some tool on sites like http://www.hidemyass.com that would allow me to use a secured connection.

If someone was to reply with just the simple language that I am missing, that would help immensely.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web server configuration and belongs on [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a reverse proxy using Apache or Nginx, it will come down to the specifics of you application. What's your application running on ? Rails, Django, Tomcat ?  All of these web apps have ways to setup `routes` that you can use to redirect all your users in case they are no authenticated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The application is its own independent processes, which hosts its own webpage. It also does not allow any routing within the application itself. I have been looking at Nginx, and an application called shellinabox, but I have not made any progress.